# Is there a way for typescript to infer types that depend on the input parameters?

Tags: typescript

The below describes what I'd like to do:

```
interface Customer {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

const getCustomer = () => {
    return {
        name: 'bob',
        age: 42
    }
}

export const getValue = (key: keyof Customer): typeof Customer[key] => {
    const customer = getCustomer();
    return customer[key];
};
```

but the TS compiler doesn't like the line `typeof Customer[key]`. I could make this `any` or `string | number`, but I *should* be able to get the type from this. For example, if I write:

`getValue('name')` what does it return? You know without any runtime information, it returns a `string`. What if I write `getValue('age')`? A `number` of course. `getValue(someInputVal as any)` might return `string` or `number`, but all of this is perfectly available at compile time. So - is there a way to get this from typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can slightly rewrite your function to use a generic:

```js
export function getValue<T extends keyof Customer>(key: T): Customer[T] {
    const customer = getCustomer();
    return customer[key];
};
```

what this is essentially saying is that `getValue` should only accept an argument that extends the keys of the `Customer` interface and it will return the associated type with that `T` key from the interface.

here is a [ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbaZAbwChlzkQ4CAuZbKUAcwG4yK4mI6R08AjaGwC+JEghwhsyLmAzZ8hALzIAFAEpkSgHzF25KBDDooIPRQuVq3ZAHJ+OfrYA0+y5xsAWAExvRokggADwAHHCgwZBh0EAQwYEkZIwA1OAAbdAgAHgAVZGDIEAATTGQAawgATxwYNCxcAihtVQrKuhz1OnkG6ABtHIBdcwoJKUiEesUoLSS5ScaNNgtDY1NkCYVG3taBkTYSWVSMiFUAIioCU-UDlPTMs6g4YvwroA) with the example solution i suggested